# Use condition of if statement as return value

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns either `false` or a number other than 0. Now I'm calling this function in another function to conditionally return the number.

```
function falseOrNumber() { ... }

function otherFunction() {
    // ...
    if (falseOrNumber()) return falseOrNumber()
    // ...
}
```

Now I was wondering, if there is an elegant way to perform this in one line without calling `falseOrNumber()` twice.

So I'm not looking for the obvious solution:

```
let i = falseOrNumber()
if (i) return i
```

This is nothing game changing, but I've encountered similar situations several times in the past and I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious solution? I mean, it works and is quite clear.

Comment: It depends if you want to use this `return` as a short circuit. If not, you can do something like this `return falseOrNumber()  || 'something else'`

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. In my specific case I just have several of these `falseOrNumber` type functions and I want to handle them all consecutively in the `otherFunction`. I want it to look nice, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign the return value of the function to a variable inside the if statement, you can re-use it with the return statement:

```js
function falseOrNumber() { ... }

function otherFunction() {
    // ...
    let result;
    if(result = falseOrNumber()) return result;
    // ...
}
```

If you want more elegance, there is probably a way to have one return statement for the entire function, instead of returning early. You can also use a comma expression to turn multiple expressions into a one-liner.

```js
function otherFunction() {
    return falseOrNumber() || (other, code, here);
}
```

Update: your comment says that you have multiple functions like `falseOrNumber`. If so, you can do this:

```js
function otherFunction() {
  return falseOrNumber() || somethingElse() || orSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Wow, the first solution is actually quite trivial. I thought about `if (let result = falseOrNumber())` but that obviously didn't work.

Comment: Also thanks for the other suggestions. The last one is nice, I will try that!

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that your use case is to call this many times over and over in the same `otherFunction`.

If you are trying to test several numbers in sequence, you can do it like so:

```js
function otherFunction() {
    return falseOrNumber(1)
        || falseOrNumber(2)
        || falseOrNumber(3)
        || falseOrNumber(4)
        || falseOrNumber(5)
        || falseOrNumber(6)
        || falseOrNumber(7)
        || falseOrNumber(8)
        || falseOrNumber(9);
}
```

If you need to do this in a loop, you can share one variable:

```js
function otherFunction() {
    let t = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        if (t = falseOrNumber(i))
            break;
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your usecase is as what @maraaaaaaaa said, in the future you might be able to do something like this if [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) gets accepted:

```js
function otherFunction() {
  const testcases = [/* ... */]; // An extremely expensive array
  return testcases.values().map(falseOrNumber).find(Boolean);
}
```

`testcases.values()` returns an iterator which goes over all elements, one by one. `.map()` map those with a function (in this case, `falseOrNumber`) on the fly, yet returns another iterator and `.find(Boolean)` returns the first mapped element which is not falsy.

Unlike `testcases.map()`, `testcases.values().map()` is lazy: it only evaluate as needed. This is also the case when it comes to both [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and `Iterator#find()` (there's no docs for this just yet, only [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator)).

Try it (this doesn't work yet):

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(
  testcases.values()
    .map(e => e ** 2)
    .find(e => e % 9 === 0)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```